# handle multiple multidimensional arrays and return as json string

Tags: php, ajax, api, laravel, guzzle

I'm connecting to API from which I'm retrieving **multiple JSON strings** via multiple GET request  using Guzzle/pool.

Json string looks like this:

```
{
  "channel":
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "my_house",
    "description": "Netduino Plus connected to sensors around the house",
    "latitude": "40.44",
    "longitude": "-79.996",
    "field1": "Light",
    "field2": "Outside Temperature",
    "created_at": "2010-12-13T20:20:06-05:00",
    "updated_at": "2014-02-26T12:43:04-05:00",
    "last_entry_id": 6060625
  },
  "feeds":
  [
    {
      "created_at": "2014-02-26T12:42:49-05:00",
      "entry_id": 6060624,
      "field1": "188",
      "field2": "25.902335456475583"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2014-02-26T12:43:04-05:00",
      "entry_id": 6060625,
      "field1": "164",
      "field2": "25.222929936305732"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I parse it and I get dimensionals arrays.

//variable **$response** store all  these JSON strings.

`$decode=json_decode($response,true).`

//$decode store all multiple dimensional arrays

If I  use `print_r($decode)`  I get all these  arrays.
It is lot of code . I put it there http://pastebin.com/N7zeRgBv

This inner array with the key **feeds** can contains different amount of next inner arrays.

Problem is also that the keys of multidimensional and inner arrays are the same. Only the values are others as you can see in pastebin file. And that's way I thing is hard to manipulate with this arrays.

How to handle this multiple multidimensional array in php? Somehow I need to send my ajax response in json format. Is there any way how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure what you are asking but that json is a multidimensional array you are just decoding it into a php array. Do you just want some values from the array? If that is the case you can loop through the array with a foreach like

```
foreach($decode as $decod) {
    $whatImLookingFor = $decod['field1'];
}
```

Comment: Also looking at the array you posted it is three different arrays. You are probably printing the same array out 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

Sending JSON is fairly easy within Guzzle.  So easy infact, that there is even a [request option](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/request-options.html#json) specifically for it.

```
// request($method, $uri, $options) proxies to requestAsync($method, $uri, $options)
// and sets the $options[RequestOptions::SYNCHRONOUS] to true
// and then waits for promises to resolve returning a Psr7\http-message\ResponseInterface instance
$response = $client->request($method, $uri, [
    'json'  => $multi_dimensional_array,
]);
```

If the content is already json encoded, all you have to do is add it as the body of your request, and, depending on the configuration of the server, set the Content-Type header.  Something like:

```
$response = $client->request($method, $uri, [
    'headers'   => [
        'Content-Type' = 'application/json',
    ],
    'body'      => GuzzleHttp\Psr7\stream_for($content),
]);
```

Comment: the response is already json string ..and I got mutliple json string